# Website with RESTful JSON API

Tags: json, web-services, rest, web

I'm keen to teach myself how to use RESTful JSON web services but cannot find any websites that implement it.

I've used SOAP before with eBay and Paypal, do you know of any large sites that use REST JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> do you know of any large sites that use REST JSON

Yes, [`Google`](https://developers.google.com/). Lots of the services they are providing are exposed through RESTful APIs.

Basically every self-respecting website today is exposing their services through RESTful APIs ready for consumption in the Cloud.

[`Apigee`](http://apigee.com/about/) is one of my favorite sites for best practices and learning REST.